# Non-SuperUser Database Management

Tags: postgresql

I am using the PostgreSql manual and other guides to setup my database environment.
So far things are looking good, but I am wondering if I have a problem.

I am trying to apply this:
Tip                                                                                         It is good practice to create a role that has the CREATEDB and CREATEROLE privileges, but is not a superuser, and then use this role for all routine management of databases and roles. This approach avoids the dangers of operating as a superuser for tasks that do not really require it.

I have already created a user for this role.

```
createuser --interactive --pwprompt
Enter name of role to add: Manager
Enter password for new role:
Enter it again:
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) y
```

...and connected to an already existing database as the new user (Manager) Or so I thought.

```
psql -d test
Password for user postgres:
psql (11.2)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

test=# \c test Manager
Password for user Manager
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
You are now connected to database "test" as user "Manager".
test=>
```

I created a table for the database "test", but on checking it,the Owner isn't Manager, but postgres.

```
test=> \dt
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 public | Data-projects | table | postgres
(1 row)


test=> \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)
```

I am not sure if this is good. I expected the owner to be Manager.
This is my first time using these tools. Can someone guide me in the right direction, please?
I want Manager to manage all the databases.
Wouldn't that make him owner?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database `test` is not owned by `Manager` because it was created by user `postgres`. The user who created an object will be its owner.

However, a superuser can transfer ownership:

```
ALTER DATABASE test OWNED BY "Manager";
```

I'll give you some additional tips:

- Only use lower case letters, numbers and `_` in the names of objects and users, because otherwise you always have to user double quotes for them in SQL, like I did above. That leads to needless suffering.
- Run the following to make the database more secure:

  ```
  REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
  ```
- Create a new schema that will hold the objects for your application:

  ```
  CREATE SCHEMA myapp;
  ```
- Set the `search_path` appropriately:

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE test SET search_path = myapp, public;
  ```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. So for clarity, Manager is managing the database, even though not owner. So I am on the right track then... everything is good - or do I need to make Manager the owner?

Comment: You don't need to, but if you don't, you should grant `manager` the `CREATE` privilege on the database, so that she can create schemas in it.

Comment: Thank you. One last thing. I can't get any of my commands to work, once I  enter a database. Do you have any idea why? test=# ALTER DATABASE test OWNED BY "Manager"
test-#  As you can see, nothin happened. This happens, regardless of the command issued.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried that before and got an error, so I thought it applied to non-Windows systems. It worked. Thanks.